# Fancybox Overlay - Facebook Like Button Popup

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, fancybox, overlay

My problem lies with the facebook like and send buttons which display a sort of popup that muddles with my layout:

normal view (no hovering over buttons or clicks):

[image]

after clicking the FB send button:

[image]

Is there a way of telling FancyBox to set the overlay to display outside of the modal box, like the GooglePlus +1 button does:

[image]

View a live example of the problem [here](http://examples.dariobauer.com/0001-facebook-fancybox/).

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this!

Comment: I've added a live example which can be found [here](http://examples.dariobauer.com/0001-facebook-fancybox/). It uses the latest facebook and fancybox (2.0.4) scripts available.

Answer (score 0):

Use fancybox 2 if you don't mind upgrading.

Cheers!

Comment: I am using fancybox 2. See live example [here](http://examples.dariobauer.com/0001-facebook-fancybox/).